# Iterating a Collection of ViewModels deriving from an AbstractViewModel and DisplayTemplates renders both DisplayTemplates

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, display-templates

(Apologies for title .. was hard to nail down)

I have a situation where a controller will build a List which will contain a set of ViewModels derived from the abstract base class. I then use display templates to render the content appropriately, but when I navigate to the url it appears to rendering the whole thing twice. Here is my code

```
public abstract class AbstractItemViewModel
{
}

public class TypeAViewModel : AbstractItemViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}

public class TypeBViewModel : AbstractItemViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Then my controller builds a test case as such.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<AbstractItemViewModel> items = new List<AbstractItemViewModel>();

        items.Add(new TypeAViewModel() { ID = 1, Title = "Test A", Body = "This is some body content." });
        items.Add(new TypeBViewModel() { Title = "Test B", Items = new List<string>() { "Line 1", "Line 2", "Line 3" } });
        return View(items);
    }
}
```

... and for completeness here is the base controller class (nothing special) ..

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{

}
```

.. and here is the View ...

```
@using xxx.ViewModels
@model List<AbstractItemViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}


<h1>@Model.Count()</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (AbstractItemViewModel item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.DisplayForModel(item)
            </div>
            <p>space</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

.. and 2 display templates
TypeAViewModel.cshtml

```
@using xxx.ViewModels
@model TypeAViewModel

<h2>@Model.Title (@Model.ID)</h2>
<p>@Model.Body</p>
```

.. and ...
TypeBViewModel.cshtml

```
@using xxx.ViewModels
@model TypeBViewModel

<h2>@Model.Title</h2>
<ul>
    @foreach (string s in Model.Items)
    {
        <li>@s</li>
    }
</ul>
```

As output I get.

> 2
>
> Test A (1) This is some body content.
>
> Test B Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 space
>
> Test A (1) This is some body content.
>
> Test B Line 1 Line 2 Line 3 space

As you can see it appears to be rendering the whole thing twice. I've placed a breakpoint and stepped through the Index View at definitely doesn't repeat the loop as such. Anybody see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `DisplayFor` Html helper instead of `DisplayForModel`, since `DisplayForModel` sends your entire model (in this case complete list of passed in models - descendants of `AbstractItemViewModel`; `item` is actually only additional data to the model passed in) to the views. Actually for every item in foreach, complete model gets passed to your view; e.g. if you would have 3 models inside your list, they would be rendered 3 times each (if 4, then 4 times, etc.).

So for this to work use this helper: `@Html.DisplayFor(model => item)` inside foreach statement instead of `DisplayForModel`.